# VBA: Received a Run-Time Error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

My code here has been working for a couple days now, but my initially condition seems to have a error now. The point section of code is to find a specific row that corresponds with a letter "A".

Is anyone can help me solve this program that would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52446630/4088852) to include your actual code - not an image of it. Images are not searchable, and people answering can't copy and paste it to the VBE.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons that you get a RTE 13 could be that the cell contains an [error value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/cell-error-values). You could add an extra if condition to avoid that

```
If Not IsError(Sheet4.Cells(x, "R")) Then
    If Sheet4.Cells(x, "R") = "A" Then
    ' ....
    End if
End if
```

Comment: When I tried this extra condition it still pass through and the error is still on the same line

Comment: You have to tell what is in the cell causing the error